# Json parse error with bashslash in the serialized object

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am calling a server side function to return a json format string and parse in client side using javascript and ajax. I got parse error at javascript. I think it is the backslash JavaScriptSerializer adds to serialize object. here is the response I see from firebug: 
{"d":"{\"Item\":\"Testing\"}"}   , i understand the backslash is to escape the double quote but how do i get json to fix this problem?? i spend 3 days and do all the search at google. It seems i am doing the same way as others. Thanks for help.

Server side Code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string testmethod(string serial)
{ 
    ItemList itemlist = new ItemList();
    itemlist.Item = "Testing";     
    return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(itemlist);
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public class ItemList
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

Client Side Javascript with ajax:

```
function PassParemeterToAspxUsingJquery(serial)
{               
    var sn = "test";//serial;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.aspx/testmethod",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{serial:'" + sn+"'}" ,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {           
       alert(msg.d);             
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert("The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown);
       alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your issue is, but that output `{"d":"{\"Item\":\"Testing\"}"}` is not the JSON you're looking for.  Something more like `{"d":{"Item":"Testing"}}` would be correct, but maybe you knew that.

Comment: thanks, i think that is the problem, javascriptserializer adds the backslash and i don't know why. Do i not use javascriptserializer in the right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebMethod` won't *embed* the value as part of the JSON text. If you want it serialized as a JSON Object rather than a JSON String, you have to return an `Object` rather than a `String`:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static object testmethod(string serial)
{
    ItemList itemlist = new ItemList();
    itemlist.Item = "Testing";
    return itemList;
}
```

Though, this may require .NET 3.5 and a [`ScriptMethodAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static object testmethod(string serial)
{ ... }
```

Then just:

```
success: function(msg) {
   alert(msg.d.Item);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you should be able to work with it as is by parsing `msg.d`:

```
success: function(msg) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);

    alert(data.Item);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your approach. i tried both but the code go directly to error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) and didnt' even go to success function so the parse code is not even reached.

Comment: @windforceus What is the `errorThrown` or does the `jqXHR.responseText` include an `Exception` message?

Comment: the textStatus shows "parse error", errorThrown doesnt show anything.

Comment: I use your 2nd approach to return as object and the response is {"d":{"Item":"Testing"}} ,seems the right Json format, i am not sure why parse error still occur.

Comment: @windforceus I'm afraid I'm at a loss, with that. It does appear to be valid JSON. Try running the response through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). Also check that the response has `Content-Type: application/json`. Or, you can try reverting back to returning the `String` and parsing it within `success` (see my edit).

Comment: Hi Jonathon, sorry for confusion. I can see the response in firebug as {"d":{"Item":"Testing"}}. but the ajax code never reach success function and it always go to error function. The textStatus in error says it is "parseerror". The return response is a valid Json in JSONLint but i dont understand why it never hit success even it is a valid response. Perhaps i need to change my contentType and dataType? They are contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 and dataType: "json".

Comment: I still can't get it to success function but i think u provide right solution. I will keep working on it.